# MongoDB: how to filter by 15 min period in a query with timestamp input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, datetime, filter

I have kind of a "simple" problem and i have thought of a "complicated" solution in my head, but i'm having problems executing it...

The thing is, i have this schema:

```
const DensitySchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    map_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    location: {
      x: Number,
      y: Number
    },
    density: Number,
    time: Number
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);
```

And I also have this query:

```
Density.find({ map_id: req.params.mapId, time: { $gte: req.query.from, $lte: req.query.to } }).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    res.send(data);
  });
```

The time and the from - to values are timestamps, for example, `1579148100`.

In the database, i have entries for timestamps that occur every 15s. But *i want to get only results of those that have happened in timestamps that have minutes that are multipliers of `15` and `0`, so `0, 15, 30, 45`*

the idea would be that if i ask for the values between, let's say, 1am and 2am, i get 4 results instead of dozens.

From what i see on mongo's documentation, i should be able to somehow filter the query request by somehow turning the time value to a readable date and then checking if the minutes are one of those values... but i guess im not smart enough to figure out how... the documentation is not so easy for me to understand yet, since i have started using mongo this week...

I would appreciate your help very much.

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp is a `long` and the corresponding time (in hours, minutes, months, etc., format) can be constructed with the `Date` field. For example, I have three timestamps and the corresponding *time* (the hour and minutes):

```
1579243569270 -> 06:46
1579243509270 -> 06:45
1579244415497 -> 07:00
```

From the *Mongo Shell*, the `new Date(1579243569270)` gets the date/time as `ISODate("2020-01-17T06:46:09.270Z")`. From this we can find the *time minutes*, which in this case is `06:46`. And, we use this in the query as follows using the `find` or the `aggregate`:

*The input collection:*

```
{ "ts" : 1579243569270 }
{ "ts" : 1579243509270 }
{ "ts" : 1579244415497 }
```

*The queries:*

```
const MINS_ARRAY = [ 0, 15, 30, 45 ]

db.test.find( { $expr: { $in: [ { $minute: { $toDate: "$ts" } }, MINS_ARRAY ] } } )
```

*_or_*

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: { 
          $expr: { 
              $in: [ { $minute: { $toDate: "$ts" } }, MINS_ARRAY ] }
          }
      }
  }
] )
```

The result will be the two documents with timestamps, `1579243509270` and `1579244415497`.

The code is tested for *Mongo Shell*. The queries use [aggegation date and array operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) which are used with the [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) to construct the queries.

---

[ EDIT ADD ]

```
db.test.find( { $expr: { $in: [ { $minute: { $toDate: "$ts" } }, MINS_ARRAY ] },
                map_id: req.params.mapId,
                time: { $gte: req.query.from, $lte: req.query.to } 
} )
```

Comment: I responded to you on an answer so i could use code formatting, im new to stackoverflow too hehe
Thx for the help!!